# How to select top 10 in Access query?

Tags: ms-access

My Access database table has 2 columns: name and price. I want to do a query that select the top 10 highest prices. How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for how to ask questions here. This is not a 'Give me teh Codez' site. Also of interest may be [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
select top 10 Name, Price
from MyTable
order by Price desc
```

**Updated**: @Fionnuala pointed out that:

> "Access SQL selects matches, so it will select all items with the
> same highest prices, even if this includes more than 10 records. The
> work-around is to order by price and a unique field (column)."

So, if you have a unique product code column, add like so:

```
select top 10 Name, Price
from MyTable
order by Price desc, UniqueProductCode desc
```

Comment: Just a quick comment - Access SQL selects matches, so it will select all items with the same highest prices, even if this includes more than 10 records. The work-around is to order by price and a unique field (column).

Comment: +1 for the fix.  I was having issues with access returning too many rows as soon as I used ORDER BY.

Comment: Extra note, this problem also occurs whilst accessing the DB from Excel using ADO. The solution here (using the arbitrary master key added to the `ORDER BY`) worked perfectly!