# Sql Statement that returns only the top 5 highest values in desc order, but the 5th en 6th value are the same?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im struggling to retrieve only 5 values from my sql Statement. I want to retrieve the 5 highest numbers in a single column. The trouble is that some of the numbers repeat. When the 5th and the 6th highest numbers are the same my sql statement retrieves 6 values and not 5. If the 5th and the 6th number are the same i dont need the 6th number from the sql. Can anyone please help?

Here is the column:

```
Number
10
9
5
5
3
3
2
1
```

My results are:

```
Number
10
9
5
5
3
3
```

I would like to retrieve only first 5 numbers excluding the 6th number.

Here is my sql:

```
10
9
5
5
3
3

SELECT TOP 5 Number 
FROM tbl
Order by Number Desc
```

Comment: how come you are getting `6` numbers - I am getting what only that much specified by `TOP` (even in case of duplicates)

Comment: and one more thing -- you should specify your DATABASE in your question and tag that as well in question

Comment: What db are you using?  I don't think the statement you gave with "TOP 5" will ever return more than 5 elements, is that part of a larger statement like `select * from tbl where Number in (select top 5 number from tbl order by number desc)`?  That would make sense.

Comment: It seems that you are using `SQL Server` (or possibly `MS Access`). Here is SQL Fiddle for SQL Server that shows 5 rows with **your** script: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d20c/2

Comment: @PM77-1 +1 was about to post the similar fiddle, seems there is some other issue with that which OP is not able to trace

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Access!

Comment: Fine, for Access take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339079/how-to-select-top-10-in-access-query). In short, include unique field in query.

Comment: Yes, I didnt think it would make a difference? There are names linked to the numbers. I want to retrieve the names but thought my problem was in the Top 5. The complete sql i used was: Select Top 5 Names From t

Comment: Select Top 5 Names From tblLearners Where  Gender ='M' Order By Number Desc

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović, thank you!Solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can group them and display like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Number 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Number
Order by Number Desc
```

or you can use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 Number
FROM tbl
Order by Number Desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Just order by number desc, and limit it to 5

```
select Number from table
order by Number desc
limit 5;
```

Note, that is MySQL syntax, i have no idea if it is "standard" for other DBs. You don't specify what DB you are using.

Comment: from the syntax it seems OP is using MS Sql Server