# How do you retrieve the top two records within each grouping

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my table, I have data that looks like this:

```
CODE    DATE    PRICE
100     1/1/13  $500
100     2/1/13  $521
100     3/3/13  $530
100     5/9/13  $542
222     3/3/13  $20
350     1/1/13  $200
350     3/1/13  $225
```

Is it possible to create query to pull out the TWO most recent records by `DATE`? AND only if there are 2+ dates for a specific code. So the result would be:

```
CODE    DATE    PRICE
100     5/9/13  $542
100     3/3/13  $530
350     3/1/13  $225
350     1/1/13  $200
```

Bonus points if you can put both prices/dates on the same line, like this:

```
CODE    OLD_DATE    OLD_PRICE    NEW_DATE    NEW_PRICE
100     3/3/13      $530         5/9/13      $542
350     1/1/13      $200         3/1/13      $225
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: C'mon, Jeff. With 50+ questions under your belt you should know what's coming.... What have you tried, and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select top 10 in Access query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339079/how-to-select-top-10-in-access-query)

Comment: @GordThompson I tried a Crosstab query with `DATE` as the heading and `PRICE` as the value, but it creates a column for every date in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it with 5 sub-queries and 1 rollup query.

First we have a subquery that gives us the MAX date for each code.
Next, we do the same subquery, except we exclude our previous results.
We assume that your data is already rolled up and you won't have duplicate dates for the same code.

Next we bring in the appropriate Code / Price for the latest and 2nd latest date.  If a code doesn't exist in the 2nd Max query - then we don't include it at all.

In the union query we're combining the results of both.   In the Rollup Query, we're sorting and removing null values generated in the union.

**Results:**

```
CODE    MaxOfOLDDATE    MaxOfOLDPRICE   MaxOfNEWDATE    MaxOfNEWPRICE
100     2013-03-03      $530.00     2013-05-09      542
350     2013-01-01      $200.00     2013-03-01      225
```

---

Using your Data in a table called "Table", create the following queries:

**SUB_2ndMaxDatesPerCode:**

```
SELECT Table.CODE, Max(Table.Date) AS MaxOfDATE1
FROM SUB_MaxDatesPerCode RIGHT JOIN [Table] ON (SUB_MaxDatesPerCode.MaxOfDATE = Table.DATE) AND (SUB_MaxDatesPerCode.CODE = Table.CODE)
GROUP BY Table.CODE, SUB_MaxDatesPerCode.CODE
HAVING (((SUB_MaxDatesPerCode.CODE) Is Null));
```

**SUB_MaxDatesPerCode:**

```
SELECT Table.CODE, Max(Table.Date) AS MaxOfDATE
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY Table.CODE;
```

**SUB_2ndMaxData:**

```
SELECT Table.CODE, Table.Date, Table.PRICE
FROM [Table] INNER JOIN SUB_2ndMaxDatesPerCode ON (Table.DATE = SUB_2ndMaxDatesPerCode.MaxOfDATE1) AND (Table.CODE = SUB_2ndMaxDatesPerCode.Table.CODE);
```

**SUB_MaxData:**

```
SELECT Table.CODE, Table.Date, Table.PRICE
FROM ([Table] INNER JOIN SUB_MaxDatesPerCode ON (Table.DATE =  SUB_MaxDatesPerCode.MaxOfDATE) AND (Table.CODE = SUB_MaxDatesPerCode.CODE)) INNER JOIN SUB_2ndMaxDatesPerCode ON Table.CODE = SUB_2ndMaxDatesPerCode.Table.CODE;
```

**SUB_Data:**

```
SELECT CODE, DATE AS OLDDATE, PRICE AS OLDPRICE, NULL AS NEWDATE, NULL AS NEWPRICE FROM SUB_2ndMaxData;
UNION ALL SELECT CODE, NULL AS OLDDATE, NULL AS OLDPRICE, DATE AS NEWDATE, PRICE AS NEWPRICE FROM SUB_MaxData;
```

**Data (Rollup):**

```
SELECT SUB_Data.CODE, Max(SUB_Data.OLDDATE) AS MaxOfOLDDATE, Max(SUB_Data.OLDPRICE) AS MaxOfOLDPRICE, Max(SUB_Data.NEWDATE) AS MaxOfNEWDATE, Max(SUB_Data.NEWPRICE) AS MaxOfNEWPRICE
FROM SUB_Data
GROUP BY SUB_Data.CODE
ORDER BY SUB_Data.CODE;
```

There you go - thanks for the challenge.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for .. the process for getting the recent date then 2nd most recent date, then the price for each date, then putting it all together. I wasn't able to work this out in my head.

Answer (score 0):

### Accessing the recent data

To access the recent data, you use `TOP 2`. Such as you inverse the data from the table, then select the top 2. Just as you start ABC from ZYX and select the TOP 2 which would provide you with ZY.

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_time DESC;
```

This way, you reverse the table, and then select the most recent two from the top.

### Joining the Tables

To join the two columns and create a result from there quest you can use JOIN (INNER JOIN; I prefer this) such as:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table_name INNER JOIN table_name.column_name ON 
table_name.column_name2
```

This way, you will join both the tables where a value in one column matches the value from the other column in both tables.

You can use a `for` loop for this to select the value for them, or you can use this inside the `foreach` loop to take out the values for them.

### My suggestion

My best method would be to, first just select the data that was ordered using the date.

Then inside the `foreach()` loop where you will write the data for that select the remaining data for that time. And write it inside that loop.

### Code (column_name) won't bother you

And when you will reference the query using `ORDER By Time Desc` you won't be using the CODE anymore such as `WHERE Code = value`. And you will get the code for the most recent ones. If you really need the `code` column, you can filter it out using and if else block.

### Reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx (Inner join)

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp (top; check the Sql Server query)

Comment: Thank you .. I didn't know `TOP 2` was a thing. I've done `TOP 10` in the past, but didn't think to try other numbers. I will give this a try!!

Comment: Sure thing, you can try out any number to select the very top values :)

Comment: It's more complicated than this, I think.  That will only give you the top 2 records, not the top 2 records by Code.

Comment: I never mentioned neither the OP that he wants top 2 records by CODE. :) He wanted the TOP 2 columns only :)

Comment: Its a matter of fact, he wanted to neglect the CODE to that he doesn't have to worry about the matching dates for different code. Isn't it like this?