# Why does this Select top 1 query return more than one result?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query here below that is part of a greater query. I intend it to return one result based on 1.) the employment ID 2.) The rate's change date. 3.) Special Rule, if exists.

```
SELECT TOP 1 rate

FROM Rate2
WHERE Rate2.entityno = 805181 
        AND Rate2.changedate <= [01/01/2011] 

        AND IIF(Rate2.SpecialRules = 'SpecialCase',
                Rate2.SpecialRules = 'SpecialCase',
                Rate2.SpecialRules = "NA")

ORDER BY Rate2.changedate DESC;
```

here is an extract of the "Rate2" table

```
EntityNo|   ChangeDate| Rate|   SpecialRules
805181| Jan-01-2010|    178.00| NA
805181| Jul-28-2012|    185.00| NA
805181| Jan-01-2010|    204.00| 'SpecialCase'
```

upon querying, i return both 204, and 178 for rates.
i just want "204", if i inputted 'specialCase' , or 178 , if i inputted "NA" . any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, and im using Access 2013.

Comment: This might help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339079/how-to-select-top-10-in-access-query -- you need to establish another unique field to include in your `order by` clause.

Answer (score 2):

If your order by is set to a value that has MORE then one result, then the top 1 row thus has more then one (date) value that meets this criteria.

So the top “1” value could result in 200 rows being the top 1 value.

You thus have more then one top date. If you introduce a second order value, then again same rules but now based on two columns. By ordering by ASC, then only one row has a top value. If you order by DESC, then obviously more then one row (date + SpeicalRules) exists with the same value.

So changing the order can most certainly effect the number of rows that are the “first” or top 1 of that data set.

If speicalRules has repeating values, and also has same date, then as noted using top 1 can produce more then one row with the same values. By changing the order, then only one actual row of data appears at the top without repeating values.

If you don’t care, and only need/want the FIRST row of the results EVEN if multiple dates exists? Then simply add the Primary Key value into the sort.

Eg:

```
ORDER BY Rate2.changedate DESC , Rate2.ID
```

This will result in a enquire order by row and only one row will be returned even if many dates are the same.

The above would return the first of the set of same dates. Assuming the auto number is incrementing, then the last most top date of the same dates could be had by flipping the sort order of the PK like this:

```
ORDER BY Rate2.changedate DESC , Rate2.ID DESC
```

So the top row of something is based on the columns you include in the ORDER BY clause. If the row repeats, then the top 1 will result in more then one row being that top 1 most value.

Adding the PK column to the ORDER by thus ensures that all rows are thus unique to the TOP 1 clause. So TOP 1 is simply driven by the rows included in the order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

per sgeddes

I have modified to include another unique field in the order by clause.

```
SELECT TOP 1 rate

FROM Rate2
WHERE Rate2.entityno = p.[test value 1] 
        AND Rate2.changedate <= [01/01/2011] 

        AND IIF(Rate2.SpecialRules = 'NewRule',
                Rate2.SpecialRules = 'NewRule',
                Rate2.SpecialRules = "NA")

ORDER BY Rate2.changedate DESC , rate2.SpecialRules ASC;
```

now it works, but only when rate2.specialrules is ASC, not DESC. can anyone advise how ASC and DESC affect text records?