# MS ACCESS Subselect “At most one record can be returned by this subquery.”

Tags: ms-access, select

Could anybody explains me why this subquery is returning “At most one record can be returned by this subquery.”?

```
(SELECT TOP 1 J.observacao " +
 " FROM tblPendenciaHistorico J " +
" INNER JOIN tblPendenciaPendenciaHistorico JH " +
   " ON J.historicoId = JH.pendenciaHistoricoId " +
" WHERE JH.pendenciaId = P.pendenciaId " +
" ORDER BY J.data DESC) AS historicoStatus"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `TOP 1` does not actually limit the result set to 1 result. That is due because Access select by matches which means that it will return 1 distinct row. So if two rows are identical, they are counted as 1 match and both will be returned. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339101/3072566). To fix this problem, you will have to include another field in your query that will make each row unique.

Comment: Tks litelite I added the pk.