# How do I limit the display of an Access subform to 10?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, subform

I have multiple combo boxes in my form (Industry, Incorporation_Date, OperatingRev), and a search button which filters the subform (as a datasheet) based on the selection of each combo box. How do I limit the display of the subform to only 10 records (by Top 10 of Operatin Revenue)? Currently it is displaying all records available with the filter.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Record Source used for your subform, your query should look like

```
SELECT TOP 10 FROM …
ORDER BY ...
```

This post discusses more about using this: [How to select top 10 in Access query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339079/how-to-select-top-10-in-access-query)

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I've tried that and it worked but how do i do it by Top 10 of only a critieria? E.g. Operatin Revenue. Have included my code as above! appreciate it :)

Comment: I may be misinterpreting your question, but Top 10 will return the first ten records of however the query is sorted (the `ORDER BY`).

Comment: So, if you sort by `[Operating Revenue Turnover]` in ascending order, you'll get the 10 records with the lowest operating revenue turnover, in order. If you sort in descending order, you'll get the 10 records with the highest operating revenue turnover.

Comment: Hi Ann!! Used Order By and it works! thanks so much :)